# How to compare a camera and an eye

Tags: eyes, human-eye

How could I compare what a normal eye can see to a camera lens?
I just went through a very comprehensive article @ [CambridgeInColor](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/cameras-vs-human-eye.htm), but I'm still not really clear.

When I take a picture with a SLR camera from an object about 30m from me: what focal length do I need to use, how should I present this picture to truly capture what the eye can see (because of the 40-60° that we see 100% everything)? And how should I print it to scale?
Are there any options so I can put a ruler, or a human being at a certain point to be able to show the differences?

I hope I'm clear here, but if not, please comment and I'll try to explain better!
What I'm aiming for is that I need a picture, but not a picture in itself, but more like what the eye will see at that position. Not what the camera registers.

Thanks

Comment: There are many questions similar to this posted on the SE Biology page (http://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=camera+eye).

Comment: @Bez I of course did a search first before posting. But the only 2 closest related articles were something about sighted Ness and my question. So I believe the question is relevant. Please correct me if not.

Comment: What exactly do you wish to achieve here? I mean, what is the practical purpose of this question? As of now the question is kind of vague and a purpose-driven approach may yield more answers to this interesting question.